# Extract subset of data from database based on FKs, and import to another database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Consider a database with 50-100 tables that **all** can trace **all** their FK dependencies directly and indirectly (up to 4-5 relationships deep) back to "Table1".

In principle, if one record of Table1 were deleted, and cascading deletes were enabled, then a subset of data would be deleted from all tables.

My goal is not to delete that data; instead I'd like to be able to **script out** (copy, not delete) **that subset of data to a file**. Then I'd like to be able to **import that data into another non-empty database with the same schema**. Of course I need to preserve all those relationships and not clash with any existing keys in the second database.

I realize this is a non-trivial task. The closest similar topic I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839220/copy-a-consistent-subset-of-data-from-one-database-to-another).  (**Edit:** This requirement is new to an existing and successful SQL database. I know it is ugly and possibly not practical.)

My question is: **What tools and techniques can I use to simplify this task?**

We're using SQL Server and currently use .NET, EF6, C#. The data subset would be about 1-3 MB in size.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Remove some speculative statements, and added example tables below where I would like to pull out all the data with relationships to a single record in Table1:

```
Table1
    Table1_Id (PK)
    Data1

Foo
    Foo_Id (PK)
    Table1_Id (FK)
    FooData

Bar
    Bar_Id (PK)
    Table1_Id (FK)
    BarData

Ding
    Ding_Id (PK)
    Foo_Id (FK)
    Bar_Id (FK)
    DingData
```

Comment: I understand the question being asked here but it really sounds like there are some serious data architecture problems. What you are trying to accomplish here is a MAJOR project that is very prone to being broken. You would have to do more than simply copying the data. You would have to also copy any of the related data if it doesn't already exist. This would take weeks or even months to write something this complicated and the performance would be horrific. This is definitely an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @SeanLange Understood. I'm wrestling with two very different use cases with cross-cutting needs. The data sub-set requirements are new and overlaid on a previously successful SQL solution. Before I say "no, we can't realistically do that" I want to sure I'm not missing anything. This is one of those requirements that at the business level seems "simple" but at the data architecture level it is quite the opposite given our current position.

Comment: Maybe a decent alternative would be to look at Change Data Capture (CDC)? It seems like maybe the business desire here is to log data changes.

Comment: Could you better explain the business case here regarding the purpose of the request? That might help drive to a better solution.

Comment: @SeanLange No, not logging changes. It's an internally consistent subset of data.    Looking back in your earlier comment you said "You would have to also copy any of the related data if it doesn't already exist." I don't follow, so maybe something about my question is misleading. I'm looking to copy out a snapshot in time of all the data that has relationships back to a record in "Table1", so it is only data that exists at that moment.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean We already have a successful SQL based solution. It runs a complex strategy game. Many users, many games. The objective is to extract just the data for one game and be able to take it elsewhere for analysis, modification, re-analysis, etc.

Comment: Let's say you have table1 and table2. The row in table2 has a foreign key to not just table1 but also table3. Now you stated you need to maintain all the relationship information. So if that row was deleted from table1 you would want that row plus the row from table2 in this process. But to maintain all your relational data you would also have to now copy the data from table3. And what if that information references yet another table? See where this is going?

Comment: I think this is why data warehouses exist. I've wrote something like what you are wanting as a pet project, but it is slow and had limitations and I never completed it because of the issues I kept running into. I think @SeanLange is correct: this is a large undertaking.

Comment: @SeanLange I see. But in our case the only "table3" we have is a handful of static status definitions that can be considered "schema". Every other table has relationships that go back to table1.

Comment: So the ONLY relationships between ALL of your tables is to table1? Instead of talking for hours and vague terms why don't you share a few tables so we can see what you are trying to do here. This is really quite silly.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry to annoy you. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Thanks. I'm also becoming more convinced this is a path we do not want to try.  (Things would be different if we had a document database from the start many years ago.)

Comment: It isn't that you are annoying me, it is that we are talking in completely vague terms. Sharing some tables gives us something solid to work with. We don't know what your table structures are or really what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Tables added. Good advice, @SeanLange

Comment: But do you have a table say Widget that has only a Ding_Id? And another table named WidgetMaket that has a WidgetID? We have now entered the realm of recursion because you need to get all of that data copied as well.

Comment: Yes, @SeanLange compared to the example, the relationships do go deeper like that.  :-(

Comment: About the only thing I can think of is to use cascading deletes across the entire set of tables. Then you also would need to have after delete triggers on every single table that would send the just deleted row to your other database. Pretty much circled all the way to the answer posted by Tab Alleman 4 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to happen OnDelete, my first thought is that you need to use triggers, and you'd either need to put a trigger on every table that is Parent in the relationship chain, or the one trigger on "Table1" would need to call a procedure that goes all the way down the chain.

Since you first want to write the deleted data to a file, I'm guessing that the second database you want to populate isn't on the same network as the first.

So what you can do, using the single trigger method, is have the trigger populate a table that simply has the PK of the row being deleted from "Table1".   Then start a job that calls an SSIS package.   The package reads the table to find out what row was deleted, and then begins a series of dataflows to create your file(s).

Finally other dataflows would upload the file(s) to the second database.  Those dataflows could be in the same package, a different package, same agent job, different agent job, depending on what works best in the details.

Alternately, if you put a trigger on every parent table, you can have that trigger perform a bulk export of the related rows in the child table.   Then a scheduled job can run every now and then and import any files it finds into the second database.

Comment: Sorry - it is not OnDelete. I "just" want to copy out a subset of data based on a specified record in that top-level Table1. I've added further wording to clarify that. Interesting idea though!

Comment: Even if it doesn't happen OnDelete, my overall strategy is still basically the same, only instead of being initiated by a trigger, it can be initiated by an application or a scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the SQL Data Compare tool, as long as each of the tables have a primary key. The tool can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30184523)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using open-source (MIT license) SqlSizer project.
I think you should be able to achieve what you want with that tool.

It allows to easily find the subset of that data, extract it and copy to empty database.

The project website:
https://github.com/sqlsizer/mssql-sqlsizer